# Identify EPSG in SQL Server

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, epsg

I have been trying to load a shapefile available at https://www.elections.on.ca/en/voting-in-ontario/electoral-district-shapefiles/open-use-data-product-licence-agreement/download-shapefiles.html to SQL Server 2014 in the EPSG: 4326 formats.

I tried this using the Shape2SQL tool available at https://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools

I checked the "Planar Geometry" option and left the "Set SRID" field unchecked. If I check the "Set SRID" field and enter 4326 in the field, nothing gets uploaded to SQL Server. Hence, I left it unchecked.

The loaded coordinates look like this and are NOT in LAT LONG form:

```
ID  ED_ID ENGLISH_NA       FRENCH_NAM       SHAPE_area    SHAPE_len  geom
1   8     Brampton Centre  Brampton-Centre  4.444118E+07  32761.97   0x000000000104B6010000A...
```

After uploading to the database, when I checked the SRID for the imported table in SQL Server using the command:

```
select distinct SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid from dbo.MYTABLE
```

It returns "0".

Please help with following questions:

1. Is the shapefile getting loaded into the SQLServer correctly?
2. How do I convert the loaded data to EPSG: 4326?

Comment: Could a SRID of 0 not just represent the default CRS, which might already be EPSG:4326?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET SP_GEOMETRY.STSrd = '4326'
```

To check it worked, first use SQL to verify the values were written correctly:

```
SELECT SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid from MYTABLE
```

(don't use distinct)

You might also ensure the coordinates are in WGS84 by selecting the geometry as text:

```
SELECT SP_GEOMETRY.STAsText()
```

Then, can you add the data to QGIS to ensure it draws correctly?

Comment: Thanks, @DPSSpatial. But, don't I need to reproject the coordinates as well?

Comment: What does geometry.STSrid() say?

Comment: It says, it is 4326 now. But the coordinates are still in the same form as mentioned in the Question. I need them in Lat and Long format.

Comment: ogr2ogr should have translated them - did you the s_srs and t_srs parameters?

Comment: and - what does geometry.STAsText say?

Comment: It says: POLYGON ((1348603.952 5495399.329, 1348602.898 5495400.304, 1348417.832 5495571.511, 1348377.883 5495590.448,...and so on))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83069/discussion-between-ravi-bansal-and-dpsspatial).